# Sum numbers from list in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have just started learning node.js. 
I am trying to create a script that will get a list from a file. The list is built like this

```
Bob:110
Mike:120
Bob:334
Dan:240
```

And will give this output

```
name value
```

It is supposed to sum the numbers associated with the same name.

So in my example it would print

```
Bob 444
Mike 120
Dan 240
```

I used the help I found in this site to create some basic script

```
fs = require('fs');
var array = fs.readFileSync('C:\\data.txt').toString().split("\n");

var items = {}, base, key;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    base = array[i];
    key = base[0];
    if (!items[key]) {
        items[key] = 0;
    }
    items[key] += base[1];
}

var outputArr = [], temp;
for (key in items) {
    temp = [key, items[key]]
    outputArr.push(temp);
}
console.log(outputArr);
```

Notice that I get the list from a text file, but it currently contains what I have posted in this question.
The output that I get is very gibberishy, and I am not sure why.
This is my output:

```
[ [ 'B', '0oo' ],
  [ 'M', '0i' ],
  [ 'D', '0a' ],
  [ 'undefined', NaN ] ]
```

Can anyone please help me understand why this does not work properly and show me how to fix it?

By the way, I am not certain if this is the correct thought line for accomplishing such a task in node.js. I would be happy to get feedback!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DLeh It is considered bad etiquette to suggest a solution using a framework or library that is not tagged or labeled in the original question.

Comment: @DavidL yes, i agree. however the top answer in this question included a vanilla js solution. i linked directly to that answer in the duplicate but it converted to just the question link.

Comment: @DLeh ah, fair enough.  If the link to answer hadn't been swallowed that would have vastly clearer.  I concur with your close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use a function to satisfy your needs:

```
function PrintAllValuesInList(name,list){
     var values = [];
     for (var i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++){
        if (list[i].name == name)
           values.push(list[i].value);
     }
     console.log("Name ",name, " Values ", values.join());       
  }
```

And a call to that would be:

```
var arr = [{ name: 'x', value: 'a'},
           { name: 'y', value: 'b'},
           { name: 'x', value: 'c'},
           { name: 'z', value: 'd'}];

PrintAllValuesInList('x',arr);
```

Would output:

```
Name  x  Values  a,c
```

Here is the plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsYXa4tEiXDRQ0PDGQqd?p=preview)

Thanks if i could help.

Comment: You might want to move the console log inside of the function :)

Comment: Sorry i was creating and posted it before it was ready. :)